# Build.gradle cannot find repository for installing secrets-gradle-platform

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

Followed the documentation step by step.

Add

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}
```

To the root build.gradle and to my app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin"
}
```

My repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
}}
```

as someone suggested on another post. I have no ideas what to do next.
Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 609ms
```

Not sure if relevant - but I did not censor out the required by/project. Thanks!

Comment: The plugin artifact you want is located in Google maven repo, I don't think that is included in gradlePluginPortal().

Comment: @Robert I also have mavenCentral in my allprojects{repositories{, didn't think to mention it, as it is default there.

Comment: But the plugin you need is not in mavencentral. It is in Google Maven repo

Comment: @Robert Interesting so what is its name? googlemaven?

Comment: @Robert I have google(), mavenCentral() and gradlePluginPortal(). Which else do I need to add